# coefficient matrix for cublasDgbmv using gpu

Tags: c, gpu, cublas

I am new at GPU and I want to solve a large matrix vector multiplication using GPU. I am trying to solve it using "cublasDgbmv" as the matrix is banded matrix. I tried to implement the command on a simple example. Here is the code I wrote:

```
/* system of equations sol=A*b:
  A=[1  2  3  0  0  0
     2 -1  4  1  0  0
     3  4  5 -1  7  0
     0  1 -1  3  8  9
     0  0  7  8  2  6
     0  0  0  9  6  10]
  b=[0 1 2 3 4 5]
  solution supposed to be (using matlab) [8 10 39 85 76 101]*/

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX(x, y) (((x) > (y)) ? (x) : (y))
#define MIN(x, y) (((x) < (y)) ? (x) : (y))

int main()
{
cublasHandle_t handle;

int i, j, k=2, m, n=6; // i,j are used as counters, k is the bandwidth, n is the size of the matrix and m is a constant that will be used in the code
double A[36] = {1,2,3,0,0,0, 2,-1,4,1,0,0, 3,4,5,-1,7,0, 0,1,-1,3,8,9, 0,0,7,8,2,6, 0,0,0,9,6,10};

double* Ab;
Ab  = (double*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));

double* b;
b   = (double*)malloc(n*sizeof(double));

double* sol;
sol = (double*)malloc(n*sizeof(double));

const double alph1 = 1;
const double *alpha_1 = &alph1;

const double alph0 = 0;
const double *alpha_0 = &alph0;

double* d_Ab;
cudaMalloc(&d_Ab, n*n*sizeof(double));

double* d_b;
cudaMalloc(&d_b, n*sizeof(double));

double* d_sol;
cudaMalloc(&d_sol, n*sizeof(double));

for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    b[i] = i;

for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
{
    m=k+1-j;
    for(i=MAX(1,j-k);i<=MIN(n,j+k);i++)
        Ab[(m+i-1)*n+(j-1)] = A[(i-1)*n + (j-1)];
}

cudaMemcpy(d_Ab, Ab, n*n*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_b ,  b, n*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cublasCreate(&handle);
cublasDgbmv(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N , n, n, k, k, alpha_1, d_Ab, n, d_b, 1, alpha_0, d_sol, 1);
cublasDestroy(handle);

cudaMemcpy(sol, d_sol, n*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%f  ", sol[i]);

free(Ab);
free(b);
free(sol);

cudaFree(d_Ab);
cudaFree(d_b);
cudaFree(d_sol);
}
```

the solution I had is:

```
4.000000  8.000000  33.000000  -31387192811020962000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000  -31387192811020962000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000  -31387192811020962000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

I know that the matrix supposed to be in bandwidth form and column major form. I did it as shown in this [link](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dgbmv.f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew the answer and I am posting it for others who may want to know it.

The banded matrix supposed to be written as mentioned in the question... But this is the format and it is supposed to be saved in column form... Thus for the mentioned example

```
A=[1  2  3  0  0  0
   2 -1  4  1  0  0 
   3  4  5 -1  7  0
   0  1 -1  3  8  9
   0  0  7  8  2  6
   0  0  0  9  6  10]
```

in the banded form as mentioned in the links I added before

```
A_banded = [3  1  7  9  0  0
            2  4 -1  8  6  0
            1 -1  5  3  2 10
            0  2  4 -1  8  6
            0  0  3  1  7  9]
```

In order to be written in the column major form it is supposed to be saved in the following form

```
A_column_major_form = {3,2,1,0,0,0, 1,4,-1,2,0,0, 7,-1,5,4,3,0, 9,8,3,-1,1,0, 0,6,2,8,7,0, 0,0,10,6,9,0}
```